# Update table if any value =

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to update my table if any value from table1 = value from table2

Table1 as 1 column with data 
Table2 as many columns with data

If table2(data) = table1(data) update

But isn't working

I had one code that was working if i set table2 with 1 column

This one is working but table2 needs to have 1 column only

```
    UPDATE table1
    SET column1 = 'correct'
    WHERE column2 in (SELECT column1 from table2);
```

I want to be able to do having more column

maybe something like this:

```
    UPDATE
    SET column1 = 'correct'
    WHERE column2 in (SELECT * from table2);
```

The error:

Result: sub-select returns 11 columns - expected 1

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do it with EXISTS:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = 'correct'
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table2
  WHERE table1.somecolumn = table2.someothercolumn
);
```

If you want to check `table1.someothercolumn` against multiple columns of `table2`:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = 'correct'
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table2
  WHERE table1.somecolumn in (table2.col1, table2.col2, ...)
);
```

Comment: There isn't a way that i can get all column without needing to specify each one from table2? 
In this part
...WHERE table1.somecolumn in **(table2.col1, table2.col2, ...)**...

Comment: No you can't with sql.